# My JsonReader class get terminated without printing any output

Tags: java, android, json, bufferedreader

I'm using the following class to read a JSON file on some URL and make a JSONObject from it. When outputting something on the screen the program gets terminated without anything in the console. This is the code:

```
public class JsonReader {

  private static String readAll(Reader rd) throws IOException {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    int cp;
    while ((cp = rd.read()) != -1) {
      sb.append((char) cp);
    }
    return sb.toString();
  }

  public static JSONObject readJsonFromUrl(String url) throws IOException, JSONException {
    InputStream is = new URL(url).openStream();
    try {
      BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is, Charset.forName("UTF-8")));
      String jsonText = readAll(rd);
      JSONObject json = new JSONObject(jsonText);
      return json;
    } finally {
      is.close();
    }
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, JSONException {
      System.out.println("in main!");
    JSONObject json = readJsonFromUrl("http://somesubdomain.domain.com/blabla.json");
    //System.out.println(json.get("id"));
  }
}
```

It's really weird because it seems it doesn't even go in the main method. I just validated the JSON file and there's nothing wrong with it. Anybody any idea? Thanks.

***EDIT: I found out that this works in a project on its own. This happens only when in the main package of the Android project.***

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this an android project?  There is no `public static void main(...)` for android projects.  You need to put this in an `Activity`.